# One to many and virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model book with a one to many relation with authors.

I want to add an attribute to a book instance called last_author that puts the latest author and can be implemented as

```
def last_author
self.authors.last.name
end
```

but when i do Book.find(1).inspect i cant see the field  last_author, but i want it. how can achieve that without writing a query to active record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why exactly you need an attribute instead of function? With the code you provided `Book.find(1).last_author` should return what you want.

If you do insist on having an attribute, you can set it manually before using, like `book.last_author = book.authors.last.name`. Not saying I recommend it, though.

Comment: It's a long story, but i need it! (for to_json.. but it's long to explain)

Comment: Oh, I see. Personally, I would go with a helper method to do conversion, then.